# Uniform convergence of the inverse (solution verification)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, inverse

Consider a continuous, increasing function $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow [0,1]$ that is onto $(0,1)$. Let $f_n$ be a sequence of non-decreasing functions converging uniformly to $f$. Show that $f_n^{-1}$ converges uniformly to $f^{-1}$ over the open interval $(0, 1)$ where we define $g^{-1}(\alpha) := \inf \{y | g(y) \geq g(\alpha)\}$.

**What I've tried**

We know that $f^{-1}$ is continuous ([Inverse of a continuous increasing function is continuous (solution verification)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4024626/inverse-of-a-continuous-increasing-function-is-continuous-solution-verification?noredirect=1#comment8308694_4024626)).

We need to show that: $\sup_{\alpha \in (0,1)}|f_n^{-1}(\alpha) - f^{-1}(\alpha)| \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Notice that:
$$|f_n^{-1}(\alpha) - f^{-1}(\alpha)| = |f_n^{-1}(f(x)) - f^{-1}(f(x))|$$

for some $x$ such that $f(x) = \alpha$ (since $f$ is onto $(0, 1)$). Now we have:

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
= |f_n^{-1}(f(x)) - x|
\end{equation}

Applying the definition of $g^{-1}$:

$$f_n^{-1}(f(x)) = \inf\{ y | f_n(y) \geq f(x)\} = \inf\{ y | f(y) + o(1) \geq f(x)\}$$

where the second equality comes from the uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$. Finally, since $f^{-1}$ is continuous: $y \geq f^{-1}(f(x)  + o(1)) \rightarrow x$ so the RHS above converges to $x$. So we have that expression (1) goes to $0$ showing the desired convergence.

I could used some feedback on my reasoning.

Comment: You only proved point wise convergence

Comment: You only proved pointwise convergence not uniform convergence

Comment: You can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175375/uniform-convergence-of-functions-spring-2002) for some hints, in a general setting. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815094/if-f-n-to-f-uniformly-does-f-n-1-to-f-1?noredirect=1&lq=1) may also help. In particular, I think you require stronger assumptions.

Comment: Thanks, if we had uniform continuity of the inverse I think I would be done, correct?

Comment: @MONODA43 Yes, indeed you would be done. But the answer below is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having proved the pointwise convergence you are in fact done, because of the following

**Claim:** Let $(h_n)$ be a sequence of non-decreasing functions, each mapping $(0,1)$ into $\Bbb R$ and converging pointwise to a continuous strictly increasing function $h$ mapping $(0,1)$ onto $\Bbb R$. Then the convergence is  uniform on compact subsets of $(0,1)$.

Fix $0<a<b<1$ and consider $h$ on the compact interval $[a,b]$.   For a large integer $m$  partition $[h(a),h(b)]$ into $m$ equal-length subintervals, with endpoints $h(a)=y_0<y_1<\cdots<y_m=h(b)$. Define  $x_k:=h^{-1}(y_k)$. Suppose $u\in[x_k,x_{k+1}]$ for some $k\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,m-1\}$. Then
$$
h_n(x_k)-h(x_{k+1})\le h_n(u)-h(u)\le h_n(x_{k+1})-h(x_k),
$$
and so
$$
\sup_{a\le u\le b}|h_n(u)-h(u)|\le\left[\max_{0\le k\le m-1}|h(x_k)-h_n(x_{k+1})|\vee \max_{0\le k\le m-1}|h_n(x_k)-h(x_{k+1})|\right].
$$
Sending $n\to\infty$ we obtain
$$
\limsup_n\sup_{a\le u\le b}|h_n(u)-h(u)|\le\max_{1\le k\le m}|h(x_k)-h(x_{k+1})|=1/m.
$$
As $m$ can be made as large as we please, $\lim_n\sup_{u\in[a,b]}|h_n(u)-h(u)|=0$.

Comment: Thanks, this reminds me of a part of the proof of the glivenko cantelli theorem (my case is simpler than GC but similar)